# How can I reset a reactive form control to originate state?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I need help with a reactive forms element. Basically, it's a required element. When the view first loads, the element is not red(not showing error that it needs a value). That is good and it only will show red if I tap inside then navigate away without filling it out. The logic I currently have is when I fill it out and submit the form... the form data gets submitted but I remain on the same page but all the previous values are wiped out. The issue with that is... now the form element thinks I didn't fill it out and is complaining when it should just not complain because technically it's a new form.

Here's my form group:

```
this.transactionForm = fb.group({
      'billNumber': [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]*$'), Validators.maxLength(30)])],
      'birthdate': [null, Validators.required],
      'transactionDate': [new Date(), Validators.required],
      'type': ['Sales', Validators.required],
    });
```

Currently,  I have a function called reset() that I call when the form is submitted:

```
reset() {
    this.transactionForm.get('billNumber').setErrors({required: false});
    this.transactionForm.controls['billNumber'].setValue('');
    this.transactionForm.controls['billNumber'].setErrors({'incorrect': false});
    this.transactionForm.controls['billNumber'].markAsUntouched();
    this.transactionForm.controls['billNumber'].markAsPristine();
    this.transactionForm.controls['birthdate'].setValue(null);
    this.transactionForm.controls['birthdate'].markAsUntouched();
    this.transactionForm.controls['birthdate'].markAsPristine();
    this.transactionForm.controls['birthdate'].setErrors({'incorrect': false});
    this.transactionForm.controls['transactionDate'].setValue(new Date());
    this.transactionForm.controls['type'].setValue('Sales');
    this.transactionForm.clearValidators();
  }
```

It's easier to get type and transactionDate to be reset to a default value but I'm not sure what I can do about birthdate or bill Number above. I tried the code above but on reset, the control is still red (and invalid).. which it should be in a new/original state. How can I fix this?

Comment: transactionForm.reset() doesnt work as expected?

Comment: @Wandrille no it doesn't. All the fields are now invalid and red.

Comment: Have a look here: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset

Comment: @R.Richards does reset() work for required fields though? It doesn't seem to work on my required fields. However, I can look at the docs and play around with it.

Comment: Definitely play around with it. If you can save the original state in a object variable that has all the values and pass that to the reset, that may be the way to go. I think it will take some trial and error to get it working.

Comment: @Euridice01 check my answer I have attached with working example

Comment: There is definitely something overriding the reset() for the form. So I need to see why thats' happening because reset() still doesn't work for me. I'm also using material design controls so idk if that could affect the behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Reset Form in Angular

Method #1 (❌ Not preferrred)

HTML:

```
<button type="reset" >Clear Form </button>
```

Method #2 (✅ preferred)

Typescript:

```
fg = new FormGroup({name:new FormControl(''),
                     nestedFg : new FormGroup({abc : new FormControl('')})
                   })  
fg.reset()  // formGroup reset 
fg.get('name').reset() // formControl reset 
fg.get('nestedFg').reset()  // Nested formGroup reset
fg.get('nestedFg').get('abc').reset() // Nested formControl reset
```

Method #1 note: it is pertinent to mention that don't use this method as type reset should avoid to use as per mozilla docs for more Info

Method #2: give more control on forms use formGroup which gives more control

Answer (score 1):

use `reset('')` and set whole form group to `pristine` via `markAsPristine()` should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

**[Reset method](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset)**

Reset the FormGroup, marks all descendants are **marked pristine and untouched**, and the value of all descendants to null.

```
this.transactionForm.reset();
```

or if you want to pass a value to the from it 's the same like use `setValue` method after form reset;

```
this.transactionForm.reset({contriolName01:'value..',controlName02:'value..'});
```

style the invalid touched vaild

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border-color: red;
}
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-reset)

Answer (score 1):

None of the above answers worked for me, so I realized it had to do something with using material elements for form group controls.

I found this bug: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190

Adding something like this fixed it for me:

```
@ViewChild(FormGroupDirective) myForm;

sendDataToBackendAndResetForm() {
  // TODO: send data to backend
  if (this.myForm) {
    this.myForm.resetForm();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't why reset didn't work for me until I passed an empty string. I wanted to reset a particular control. Form was built with formbuilder and Angular 8.

Did something like `this.transactionForm.get('billNumber').reset('')`